# Methods In Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, methods

I'm looking for some advice.

I'm creating an Mp3 type project that has both client application (which has  GUI) and web service application.  This is programmed in C#.

In the web service application I have created a Method for copying a playlist, Method for copying a song and a Method that allows the for both other Methods to be pasted.

My question is, should these Methods be removed from the web service side and programmed in the client application instead or am I write in creating the Methods on the web server?

Comment: Copying or streaming?

Comment: copying, the idea is that when the client presses the copy button that the data will b saved in the copy method, but not sure if I need a copy in the web server side or just create the copy function in the client GUI